# How to emulate case-when for linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-6

```
IQueryable a;
IQueryable b;

IQueryable res = from ab in a.Union(b)
select {
    prop = ab.prop,
    deletable = ab.type == CONSTANT_TYPE && 
    (from d in deletableTable 
     where key = CONSTANT_KEY
     select d).FirstOrDefault().RenderCode == CONSTANT_RENDER_CODE
};
return res;
```

The code from the above raise the error

> `b` appears in two structurally incompatible initializations
>   within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in
>   two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set
>   in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

I not sure what is the reason, but I guess, that as I'm returning IQueryable it fails to build the sql string because of `d in deletableTable ? true : false`.

In sql it looks like

```
SELECT 
case
    when (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM deletable) = CONSTANT then true
    else false
end
```

Is some workaround exists for linq if I want to return IQueryable?

Comment: Where does `d in deletableTable ? true : false` appear in your query? Your code doesn't seem to show anything that could generate that error.

Comment: @NetMage you are right I have missed important detail, but at that time I didn't know that it is important, I have fixed the issue, check the answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message from the question was caused because deletable was missing in queryable a and queryable b.

```
IQueryable a = getA();
IQueryable b = getB();

IQueryable res = from ab in a.Union(b)
select {
    prop = ab.prop,
    deletable = ab.type == CONSTANT_TYPE && 
    (from d in deletableTable 
     where key = CONSTANT_KEY
     select d).FirstOrDefault().RenderCode == CONSTANT_RENDER_CODE
};
return res;
```

`getA` and `getB` originally have returned objects with property `prop`.

If you want to do `from ab in a.Union(b) select deletable = 12` , even uf 12 it constant from your code, the `deletable` field should be declare in querybable a, and in queryable b, otherwise you will the error from question.

I have added declaration of `deletable` to fix the error:

```
getA() {
    from a ...
    select new {
        prop,
        deletable = false //add field, to use union
    }
}

getB() {
    from b ...
    select new {
        prop,
        deletable = false //add field, to use union
    }
}
```